# package org.jivesoftware.smackx.carbons does not exist

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

Try to move from Asmack to Smack 4.1 in Android application. When try to build got next error.

package org.jivesoftware.smackx.carbons does not exist.

I checked the documentations. There is such package and all files I need.

Anybody know what the problem?

Trying to add next dependencies:

```
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.7"
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.7"
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.7"
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.7'
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-java7:4.1.7"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Forgot to add

```
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-experimental:4.1.7'
```